# JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray 4

Tags: android, json

I already searched for many type of solutions, but I still don't know how to change it and solve my error.  I need someone help, because I quite new in android.

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"user_info":[{"MemberID":"1","Name":"Joshua","Url":"joshua@gmail.com"},{"MemberID":"2","Name":"Mary","Url":"mary@gmail.com"}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Here are my variables and the code that parses the JSON-File:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    TextView id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);
    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView url = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.url);

    JSONObject json = null;
    String str = "";
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost user_info = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.103/ViewList/getJSON.php");

    try {
        response = myClient.execute(user_info);
        str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
        json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);

        id.setText(json.getString("MemberID"));
        name.setText(json.getString("Name"));
        url.setText(json.getString("Url"));

    } catch ( JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to read the actual `JSON` string as `JSONOBject` first, and then read the key `"user_info"` as a `JSONArray` . Here are the changes:

```
try{
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
        //then here you read user_info as array 
        JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("user_info");
        json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);

        id.setText(json.getString("MemberID"));
        name.setText(json.getString("Name"));
        url.setText(json.getString("Url"));

    } catch ( JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Give that a try and let us know if it solves your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion, finally is worked to me.

Comment: Excellent. I am glad this helped you. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're feeding the `JSONArray` object the string that starts with a `JSONObject`. The class `JSONObject` also has a method `getJSONArray` which you should use:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(str);
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("user_info");
```

And then, you can loop over `jArray`.

Comment: I was looking at OP's string through a validator so I wanted to ask you, is there an instance where a JSON string actually begins as an array? I suppose it would look like like { [? is this possible? and in that case then you would use `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);` correct?

Comment: No, your other example is also not valid. Objects in JSON always have a key. And it is valid JSON to just send an array starting with [].

Comment: That last sentence is not a bit clear to me, can you have JSON that starts with [, which would be an array of course.

Comment: Yes it's possible. The example you gave that stars with `{[` is not valid, because if you open an object in JSON, you must give a key before giving a value.

Comment: I see what you mean, I was just thinking that you needed to always have { to open JSON. Next question, is my JSONArray declaration correct? Is that how you would pass the raw JSON to get started?

Comment: @DanielK if your JSON starts with `[`, then yes, you should declare it with `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);`